# Can objects be linked in Gamemaker?

Tags: game-maker

Within the game I'm currently building there's an interactive element that is supposed to work the same way when interacting with different elements. To make it easier to replicate numerous times, I duplicated the objects containing this code and changed the global.variable which is supposed to define each individual 'group' (two objects make up the element itself) so they work separately - however when I interact with one group in the game, it still triggers the other one to react at the same time.

Can objects be linked in gamemaker? And if so, how do I unlink these objects so that they work separately?

Here's the code for both in case it's more an issue with something in the code that I've overlooked. Basically how the group works is that when the player interacts with the object, the object changes it's instance and the new object picks up the functionality of the old one. First three image in each group refer to the first object, last three refer to the second.

**Group 1 Object 1;**

Create Event

```
global.ssscollission = 0;
```

Key Press E

```
if (global.ssscollission = 0)
{
global.ssscollission = 1;
}

else
{
global.ssscollission = 0;
}

instance_change(obj_snakeplush,false)
```

Draw GUI

If Collision, Stop Movement, Font Text and Draw Value DnD features here

.

**Group 1 Object 2;**

Draw GUI

If Collision, Stop Movement, Font Text and Draw Value DnD features here, as well as;

```
if (global.ssscollission)
{
draw_set_color(c_black);
draw_set_alpha(0.75);
draw_rectangle(0,0,room_width,room_height,0);
draw_set_alpha(1);
draw_set_color(c_white);
draw_set_halign(fa_center);
draw_sprite_ext(spr_sss,0,920,50,0.65,0.65,0,c_white,1);
draw_set_font(fnt_credit);
draw_text(1275,1400,"Press the [E] button to return.")

}
```

Key Press E

```
if (global.ssscollission = 0)
{
global.ssscollission = 1;
}

else
{
global.ssscollission = 0;
}
```

Animation End

```
image_index = image_number - 1;
image_speed = 0;

global.danielfound = global.danielfound + 1
```

.

**Group 2 Object 1;**

Create Event

```
global.danieltree = 0;
```

Key Press E

```
if (global.danieltree = 0)
{
global.danieltree = 1;
}

else
{
global.danieltree = 0;
}

instance_change(obj_danieltree,false)
```

Draw GUI

If Collision, Stop Movement, Font Text and Draw Value DnD features here

.

**Group 2 Object 2;**

Draw GUI

If Collision, Stop Movement, Font Text and Draw Value DnD features here, as well as;

```
if (global.danieltree)
{
draw_set_color(c_black);
draw_set_alpha(0.75);
draw_rectangle(0,0,room_width,room_height,0);
draw_set_alpha(1);
draw_set_color(c_white);
draw_set_halign(fa_center);
draw_sprite_ext(spr_sss,0,920,50,0.65,0.65,0,c_white,1);
draw_set_font(fnt_credit);
draw_text(1275,1400,"Press the [E] button to return.")

}
```

Key Press E

```
if (global.danieltree= 0)
{
global.danieltree= 1;
}

else
{
global.danieltree= 0;
}
```

Animation End

```
image_index = image_number - 1;
image_speed = 0;

global.danielfound = global.danielfound + 1
```

Cheers

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Ah, I'll update my post now.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're after but all your objects react to pressing "E".  It looks like when you press E, the first object in each group will flip its global variable, but the second object in each group will flip that variable straight back to what it was before you pressed E.  

And every time you press E, both groups will react. So the first time you press E, both object 1 in each group will change to a different object.

It's hard to give an answer because I don't know what you are trying to achieve